# Copy a file content to clipboard with dired

Tags: dired

I would like to emulate the fonctionnality of `xclip` in dired. That is, copying file content to clipboard (but without opening it in Emacs).

Sadly, using `dired-do-async-shell-command` and `xclip` does not work.
Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(save-window-excursion
    (dired-find-file)
    (kill-new (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))
    (kill-current-buffer))
```

Answer (score 4):

@nichijou's answer is fine.  But there's no need to actually put the buffer in a window.  You can use `find-file-noselect` to visit a buffer without displaying it.

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf  (find-file-noselect (dired-get-file-for-visit))))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (kill-new (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
    (kill-buffer buf)))
```

Comment: Could you explain why you have to store the buffer in the "buf" variable ? It looks like it read the file twice.

Comment: @alex_reader: Duh; good catch. Fixed. I forgot to replace the sexp by the variable. I added the variable so I could kill the buffer when done.

Comment: I rejected an edit that added a non-nil `RAW` arg to the `find-file-noselect` call. Not sure the rejection was correct (had to reject or accept), but it's not clear to me why the answer to the *question calls* for non-nil `RAW` as part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error, and want to suggest that you're possibly using `xclip` incorrectly. This answer should also benefit others because no-one needs to create a custom emacs function for this to work.

From a `dired` buffer, I select a small-sized file, and enter `&` to get the async dialog. Then I enter `xclip -i`. That sends the contents of the selected file to the PRIMARY clipboard, one of the three clipboards present in all modern GUI environments (the other two are called SECONDARY and CLIPBOARD). Then, from a terminal emulator outside emacs, I run `xclip -o` and I do see the contents of that file inserted into the terminal.

If you want `xclip` to operate on the CLIPBOARD clipboard (I know, it is confusing, I didn't design it), then pass it the arguments `-selection clipboard`. Personally, I have it defined as a shell alias. There also exists the command-line program `xsel`, which has shorter option names.